# print function in ruby

Tags: ruby, gets

I'm a ruby beginner. I have the following code which asks the user for his name and prints it back.

```
print 'Enter your name : '
name = gets()
print("Hey,#{name} !")
```

If I enter John Doe as the name, the output is as follows

```
Hey,John Doe
!
```

`print` unlike `puts` does not automatically put a new line after output but I've noticed that in the above case anything I enter after `#{name}` is printed on a new line. Why is this so ?

Comment: hint: `name` contains a character you typed in (pressed a key for) but are not expecting.

Comment: Oh yeah, the newline character ! :D...thank you ! :)

Answer (score 5):

`gets()` is returning the newline caused by you pressing the enter key. Try `name = gets().chomp` to trim it off.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on OS X, and running this in irb, you could also type in "John Doe" and then press control+d twice.

I think the equivalent for windows is control+z.

Also, if you did `print name.inspect`, then you'd find out for sure that `name` contains a newline - it'd print out `"John Doe\n"`.